# High traffic MySQL database solution

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

So I'll wondering about moving to a serious database solution. I am preparing to maintain a website that has 1 million users that are using the site at about a few hundred at any given time.

We use about 7 GB of data and maintain about 40 tables ranging from 35 million records to only about a few thousand records.

We have caching and maintain a single database server at about 100,000 users now. We use CakePHP to power our site. We need to plan getting bigger and I'm in charge.

I am studying diligently, but I want to know what the cool kids at stack trust to manage this scale of database.

I have reviewed Amazon's solution, Cassandra, sharded databases, mysql confederated db, and NBD cluster.

I want to power this solution with mysql, and I'm asking because I an interested in current wise solutions.

Methodologies, tools, and appropriate engines that are used for this are what I am wondering about. I will continue to research.

I'm trying to mitigate the amount of server power I need. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things vary a lot per case so there is no way to say something really useful about it without much more data.

But if you simply want to know how others do it, have a look at this blog: http://highscalability.com/

As for stack... view the blog: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Cool, that blog is basically what I was hoping to find. Thank you.